# Заявить о рекламации / заявить рекламацию

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

*Заявить о рекламации* — можно ли так сказать?
Меня смущает предлог "о". *Заявить рекламацию* — это правильно, так мне кажется.

Comment: Если можно, напишите пример использования,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что имеется в толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[рекламация](https://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Reklamacija-42075.html), -и; *ж.* [от лат. *reclamatio* — неодобрение, возражение] Торг., экон. Претензия по поводу низкого качества товара или услуги с требованием возмещения убытков. ***Заявить рекламацию.** Рекламация на плохую окраску ткани. Обратиться на завод с рекламацией. **Предъявить рекламацию.***

Управление:
[заявить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — 1. [предъявить, представить что-л.] **что**. *Заявить свои права на наследство; Заявить протест; Заявить отвод чьей-либо кандидатуре.*

> **Рекламация (претензия)** — коммерческий документ, в котором содержится претензия к стороне, нарушившей принятые на себя по контракту обязательства, и требование возмещения убытков.
> Рекламация обычно состоит из трёх частей: (1) основания для предъявления претензии; (2) доказательства (акт экспертизы, акт приёмки и т. д.); (3) конкретные требования стороны, предъявляющей претензию (например, замена некачественного товара качественным, уценка и т. д.).
> Языковые конструкции для выражения рекламации: *Мы официально **заявляем** Вам **рекламацию** на... Наши клиенты **заявили рекламацию**...*
> [Русский язык и культура речи](https://libraryiksu.kg/public/assets/upload/books/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8.%20%D0%95%D0%BB%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0.pdf5e54d0f4eaa66.pdf) (учебное пособие; коллектив авторов; стр. 106)

*В случае возникновения спора в отношении качества поставленного топлива сертификатам покупатель имеет право оспорить качество топлива и **заявить рекламацию*** (В. Ф. Попондопуло. Д. А. Петров. Бункеровка судов газомоторным топливом: правовое регулирование).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне интересно почему в книге "Тестовый практикум по русскому языку делового общения
Базовый сертификационных уровень" Н. В. Большакова [и др.]на
стр.217 п. 18  написано “заявить о рекламации”. Это ошибка в книге? Есть ли пример предложения "заявить О рекламации"?